# Uniform plugin and select box issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am really baffled at this issue because I have no idea where the problem is at, nor do I know where to begin.

I have two selects as you can see in the image. The one to the left is fine but the one on the right is much smaller than the content within it. I personally believe the issue is with the plugin but again, I don't know where to look.

Here is what I've done. I've disabled the plugin and the select box comes back to full size and the onchange event works as expected. When I enable it again, the onchange is more like a mouseup event because the instant you click on the select, you're forwarded over to another page; it won't allow you time to make a selection.

Can anyone shine a little joy over this way, please?

[image]

Comment: To me this seems more like css issue. Have you checked css with firebug?

Comment: @Sharique, I think you may have a point about the CSS, however, I think it may also be a markup issue. For the first time in over 2 hours, I was able to make a little headway. I used some `<option>` tags directly in my HTML and it's working as it should. The onchange is also working. Let me ask you a question. I'm building these option tags server-side and then with AJAX, putting the output into the select. Is this ok?

Comment: This is what the server is sending back: `{"tags":"<option value=\"0\">No Saved Lists<\/option>"}` and is what I expect to see in the dropdown

Comment: You need to check plugin documentation

Comment: OK, I've already looked but wasn't able to find abything useful. I'll go look again

Comment: can you share the link of plugin?

Comment: Sure. THanks for having a look. I'm stumped... Here's the URL: uniformjs.com